# How to use varibles in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use the date variable in Oracle, I wrote a simple statement, but it doesn't work, can anyone help me to fix this, thx

Frank

```
Declare 
StartDate Date := to_date('03/11/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
Begin
SELECT
  REQUESTED_DATE.CALENDAR_DATE,
  Count( distinct FD_DW.SALES_HEADER_FACT.SALE_ID) INTO StartDate
FROM
  FD_DW.DATE_DIM  REQUESTED_DATE,
  FD_DW.SALES_HEADER_FACT
WHERE
  ( REQUESTED_DATE.DATE_KEY=FD_DW.SALES_HEADER_FACT.REQUESTED_DATE_KEY  )
  AND  
  REQUESTED_DATE.CALENDAR_DATE  = StartDate
GROUP BY
  REQUESTED_DATE.CALENDAR_DATE;
 End;
```

Error message:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can read and write the same variable in the same statement. Was that really your intention?

Comment: What are trying to do with this variable? BTW, The error says, you cannot fetch the values from two columns into a single variable.

Comment: You are trying to squeeze values of two columns into one variable, thus the error. There are must be as many variables as many columns(literals) are specified in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: If I only have read only access, so I cannot write variables, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
declare 
    StartDate Date := to_date('03/11/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
    n_count integer; 
begin
select cnt INTO n_count from
( 
SELECT 
  REQUESTED_DATE.CALENDAR_DATE, 
  Count( distinct HEADER_FACT.SALE_ID) as cnt
FROM
  FD_DW.DATE_DIM          REQUESTED_DATE,
  FD_DW.SALES_HEADER_FACT HEADER_FACT
WHERE
  REQUESTED_DATE.DATE_KEY = HEADER_FACT.REQUESTED_DATE_KEY  and
  REQUESTED_DATE.CALENDAR_DATE  = StartDate
GROUP BY REQUESTED_DATE.CALENDAR_DATE
)
;
end;
```

Comment: thanks so much, still not work for me, because i only have read only access to the database???